# copy/Paste Range not the Same: Error...why is this happening?

Tags: excel, vba, consolidation

I am working on copying and pasting ranges from multiple workbooks into a masterfile.

I have am having trouble pasting one workbook, as it is telling me the copy/paste range is not the same....do you know why this is happening? It is working for a few other workbooks before it but not working once it gets to the third workbook.

Code below:

Sub MasterFile()

```
'OpenMF
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\MasterFile.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False

'AdminBase

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\2019ResourcePlan-BaseAdmin-Working.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="VWMTA2019!"
   Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
   On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
   On Error GoTo 0
   Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-BaseAdmin-Working.xlsm").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy

Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-BaseAdmin-Working.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Epstein
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\2019ResourcePlan-Epstein-Working01-09-2019.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="ccce2019"
   Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
   On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
   On Error GoTo 0
   Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-Epstein-Working01-09-2019.xlsm").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy

Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-Epstein-Working01-09-2019.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Deir
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\2019ResourcePlan-GFCC-Working_Deirv4.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="GFCC2019rft"
   Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
   On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
   On Error GoTo 0
   Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-GFCC-Working_Deirv4.xlsb").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy

Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-GFCC-Working_Deirv4.xlsb").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Maria
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\2019ResourcePlan-GFCC-Working_Palazzotto.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="GFCC2019rft"
   Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
   On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
   On Error GoTo 0
   Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-GFCC-Working_Palazzotto.xlsb").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy

Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-GFCC-Working_Palazzotto.xlsb").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Thummala
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\zk4h90v\Desktop\Radley Files\2019ResourcePlan-Thummala-Working20190109.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Password:="eit19ccor"
   Worksheets("Resource Plan").Activate
   On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Resource Plan").ShowAllData
   On Error GoTo 0
   Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-Thummala-Working20190109.xlsm").Worksheets("Resource Plan").Range("A4").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy

Workbooks("MasterFile").Activate
Workbooks("MasterFile").Worksheets("2019").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("2019ResourcePlan-GFCC-Thummala-Working20190109.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

thank you!

Comment: You should [avoid using activate and select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your scripts

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad beat me to the comment :) but also, which line throws the error? is it when you are attempting to open the third file? or when you are attempting to unhide rows and columns? Also, please seriously consider cybernetic.nomad's comments. `Select` and `Activate` do more harm than good

Comment: Merged cells on the 3rd source sheet perhaps?